# Why can't I assign a value to a decimal with a ternary operator?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of objects (using anonymous types) containing a decimal and an integer ID, and I'm building a function to take the sum of the decimals contained within all unique objects in the list.

This is the line of code I wrote:

```
var result = (objectList.Any()) ? objectList.Distinct().Sum(x => x.DecimalValue) : 0;
```

However, it always returns a decimal with the value `0`, even though it should be returning the sum - objectList contains five identical objects in my example, so it should return the DecimalValue.

If I replace it with these two lines of code, however, it returns the DecimalValue:

```
decimal result = 0;
if (objectList.Any()) result = objectList.Distinct().Sum(x => x.DecimalValue);
```

Why does the second set of lines work, but the first line returns the wrong value? `objectList.Any()` is true, so it shouldn't be using the false assignment.

**Update:** I generated the list of anonymous types using this line of code:

```
var objectList = _ms.Read(cmd, x => new { DecimalValue = x.Field<decimal>("SomeColumnName"), Id = x.Field<int>("SomeColumnId") }).ToList();
```

`_ms` is a DAO for MS SQL, and it's running the lambda function that converts each datarow of the results to the anonymous typed object, which is returned in a list. I actually haven't been able to figure out how to build a list of those objects manually.

**Another Update:** Using Reed Copsey's reply below, I created the list manually in a way that duplicates the list that I'm getting, and I can reproduce the error with the manually created list:

```
var objectList = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(i => new { DecimalValue = (decimal)31.45, Id = 3 }).ToList();
var result = (objectList.Any()) ? objectList.Distinct().Sum(x => x.DecimalValue) : 0;
```

I also tried removing the cast to decimal, and the issue is still present.

**Another Update:** After some further debugging I realized something I've never come across before. I set a breakpoint immediately after the line of code I mentioned that was having problems in each case. For the workaround, it returned 31.45. For the problem line, it returned 0. When I stepped into the next line, and looked at the variable again, it said 31.45. The line I set the breakpoint on did not access or modify the variable.

It would seem that both lines work, but that the debugger showed that it did not until I moved at least two lines after the code. I've never come across that before, but it shows that the code indeed does work.

Comment: What is the type of `var result` after you assign the value?  Is it possible C# is inferring an incorrect type (of say `int`) from the ternary expression?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your first statement - the outcome should be the same

Comment: What does `objectList` contain?  If you define it as `var objectList = new List<decimal> { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };` I get `5` as the result of your ternary expression (obviously removed `DecimalValue`), so it has to be something to do with the type.  We need to see what the list contains.

Comment: Can you post the code that constructs `objectList`?

Comment: What happens if you change the first line to use 0.0 as the literal alternative (instead of 0)?

Comment: In your fist line of code, does using decimal result = ... give the same results as var result =... ?

Comment: You're going to have to post a small, complete repro that actually compiles. The code as given is fine.

Comment: @hardmath - if there was a typing issue, shouldn't it be `0m` (decimal) rather than `0.0` (double)?

Comment: @hardmath, then he would have an issue because a double is not implictly convertible to a decimal, nor is a decimal implicitly convertible to a double. An `int` is implicitly convertible to either, so it *shouldn't* be a data conversion or type inference issue.

Comment: I tried your expression with `var objectList = new[] { new { DecimalValue = 1.0M }, new { DecimalValue = 1.0M } };`, and it returns 1.0M as expected. There's definitely something else going on that we cannot see from your code snippet.

Comment: Are you sure sum of decimal values is not zero? or each decimal value is not zero?

Comment: Don't really understand all these upvotes for a completely mystic and unclear question.

Comment: I updated the post with as much as I think I can post about how objectList is generated.

Comment: "I actually haven't been able to figure out how to build a list of those objects manually." 1) *Define a concrete type.* 2) Then declare a list of that concrete type. 3) Then manually create objects of that type and 4) add those to the list. When you're using anonymous types, you are foregoing a lot (but not all) of the compile time features.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram So you're saying that the problem is being caused by simply using anonymous types? Or are you saying there is a way of declaring an anonymous type's type, and then making a list based on that?

Comment: The issue (not related to the question, just the comment about the list) is that *you* can't explicitly declare a list of a type you haven't defined. `var list = new List<???>();` If you're using an anonymous type, you are basically leaving it in the compiler's hands to obtain a list (as you're doing in your code). If you want to exert greater control, simply define a type `class Foo { /* details */ }` and then `var list = new List<Foo>();` Again, this says nothing about your presently non-reproducible issue in the question.

Comment: @JimCloudman Have you checked in the debugger to make sure your List is being filled correctly?  The code you're showing should populate something similar to my answer, provided the results coming back from the DB are correct.  I would verify that first...

Comment: @ReedCopsey I updated the post with a manually-created list which produces the same issue. The types in the list that's returned are identical to this one.

Comment: @JimCloudman That works, too - see my updated answer... (Also verified that it works properly, and returns the same value in .NET 3.5 & 4.0)

Comment: @JimCloudman What framework version are you targetting?  What compiler and runtime?

Comment: It works when I have that in a separate, empty console project, it turns out, but not in the project that I need the function in. Those two lines are all independent variables, no other part of the application touches them... and the issue is still appearing there. I don't have any explanation, and short of posting the entire codebase I don't know what else to do.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Target framework is .NET Framework 4, compiler is MSBuild and I'm using Visual Studio 2010 SP1.

Comment: @JimCloudman Have you checked it in a debugger?  When you step through, is the value set appropriately, then being changed, maybe?  How are you displaying/inspecting the value?  Perhaps the "display" mechanism isn't handling decimal correctly, and converting it to a zero...

Comment: @ReedCopsey I've stepped through each line, and when I didn't find anything I created test lines right in front of each one to see for sure what the values were. objectList.Any() returns true, objectList.Distinct returns a list with a single object of {31.45, 3}, objectList.Distinct().Sum(x => x.DecimalValue) returns 31.45, and my 2-line workaround method returns 31.45 as well. The result of the method that doesn't work is still zero, however. Those are all the values at the time of running that function.

Comment: @ReedCopsey I just realized something really strange: if I set the breakpoint on the line immediately after the function is run, it's set to zero. If I hit F10 and go to the next line, it's 31.45. That line is a conditional statement completely unrelated to that variable. This works with both the real data and the fake data. If it holds up and the correct data makes it through the whole class, then perhaps it's just an odd debugger quirk that's been throwing me off all this time...

Comment: The data is good... well, I certainly didn't expect the problem to be a quirk with the debugger. Is this something that happens occasionally in Visual Studio? Otherwise I should look into that more.

Comment: @JimCloudman: Are you trying to debug in release mode by chance? That would explain it

Comment: @BrokenGlass Nope, debug mode.

Answer (score 11):

There is no problem with your statement.

The issue is elsewhere, most likely in how you're constructing `objectList`.

For example, the following works exactly as expected, and prints "0.6" (as would be expected):

```
namespace Test
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;

    internal class TestCompile
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var objectList = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(i => new { ID = i, DecimalValue = i / 5.0m }).ToList();

            decimal result = objectList.Any() ? objectList.Distinct().Sum(x => x.DecimalValue) : 0;

            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Update:

In response to your update, this also works perfectly:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var objectList = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(i => new { DecimalValue = (decimal)31.45, Id = 3 }).ToList();
    var result = (objectList.Any()) ? objectList.Distinct().Sum(x => x.DecimalValue) : 0;

    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

It is using the exact code you pasted, and reports `31.45`, as expected (due to the unique constraint).  Note that, personally, I would use `31.45m` instead of the cast, but it works even as written...

Comment: -1, is not valuable answer as the upvotes says, like my downvote for question.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri That's fine - it is, IMO, a very valuable answer, as it's proof that the issue is not what the OP suspected, but rather something else happening elsewhere in his code.

Comment: That's your idea and may be upvoters, but IMO 50% of people commented for question or commented on wrong answer know this isn't problem.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: But obviously the OP does not.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri A comment wasn't doing the trick.  I made a full repro, showing exactly what the OP was describing, and how it works correctly.  This is far beyond what can be included in a comment...

Comment: @EdS. OK you think OP is dump? and in all again it's not nice answer as is right now. and all of this is my opinion. and IMO upvotes are just saying questioner is wrong, or my idea is  wrong, or friendship or ... not because of 2 line simple code.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: Well... I think you meant "dumb", not "dump", but I have no idea.  All I know is that the OP did not distinguish his problem between his case and a more simple case before posting the question.  He assumed it was a problem with the ternary, but it is not.  How can I assume that he knows the problem is not the ternary when his question states otherwise?

Comment: @EdS. I mean after comments OP can understand it.(not when he posting the question.)

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: Ok, well you're entitled to your opinion and downvote, as are we.  I upvoted because it is the only answer that makes sense at this time, even though I posted essentially the same thing as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, your code works though I had to make up my own type.

```
[Test]
public void X()
{
    var objectList = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(d => new {DecimalValue = Convert.ToDecimal(d)});

    var result = (objectList.Any()) ? objectList.Distinct().Sum(x => x.DecimalValue) : 0;

    Assert.AreEqual(55, result);
    Assert.AreEqual(typeof (decimal), result.GetType());
}
```

Too big for a comment so CW it is.

Answer (score 0):

I just compiled a code

```
    public class ObjectValue
    {
        public Decimal DecimalValue { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var objectList = new List<ObjectValue>() { new ObjectValue() { DecimalValue = 5 }, new ObjectValue() { DecimalValue = 5 } ,
                    new ObjectValue() { DecimalValue = 5 }};


            var result = (objectList.Any()) ? objectList.Distinct().Sum(x => x.DecimalValue) : 0;

            decimal resultDecimal = 0;
            if (objectList.Any())
                resultDecimal = objectList.Distinct().Sum(x => x.DecimalValue);

        }
    }
```

And `result` and `resultDecimal` are `15`, in my case. I have coherent result in both cases provided, as I expected. So the error is somewhere else.